# Casting in c++ not working as expected

Tags: c++, casting

This small program is made to figure out the first and second digits of a 2 digit number. However, when I try using it on the number 99 then it prints 9 and 8, but other 2 digit numbers seem to work fine though. This is probably trivial, but I'm relatively new at programming.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int num) {

    float numValue = (num*1.0) / 10;
    cout << numValue << endl;
          // prints 9.9

    int firstDigit = num / 10;
    cout << firstDigit << endl;
         // prints 9

    int secondDigit = (numValue - firstDigit) * 10;
    cout << secondDigit << endl;
         // prints 8, supposed to be (9.9 - 9) * 10

}

int main()
{
    test(99);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Floating-point numbers here serve only to confuse and annoy.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It's long, but it answers your question...

Comment: Thanks guys, I would +1 your comments but I don't think I'm able to yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `(numValue - firstDigit)` is not exactly 0.9, but rather `0.89999...`, because floating-point numbers are not accurate generally. So when you multiply `0.8999...` by 10, you get the result of `8.999...` However, then you are putting it into an `int` variable, so it gets trimmed and becomes exactly 8.

You don't really need floating point arithmetic for your exact task though, using integers will be enough.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation, I'll keep this in mind. I'll upvote as soon as I have 15 rep :)